# Runtime Error(SIGSEGV)

Tags: c

I am new to coding. When I am submitting my code in codecheff its giving "Runtime Error(SIGSEGV)". I Don't know what's the problem please help. Thanks in advance.

```
int call(int *x, int m)
{
   int b[10], y, z;
   for(y = 0 ; y<m ; y++)
   {
      int sum = 0;
      z = *x;
      while(z>0) {
         sum = sum + z/5;
         z=z/5;  
      }
      b[y] = sum;
      x++;
   }

   for(y = 0 ; y<m ; y++)
      printf("\n%d", b[y]);
}

int main() 
{
   int n=0, i=0, a[10]; 
   scanf("%d", &n);
   for(i=0;i<n;i++){
      scanf("%d", &a[i]);
   }
   call(a, n);
   return 0;   
}
```

Comment: What if `n > 10`? It will likely to give you this error.

Comment: What is the specification of this function?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Debugger..........................................

Comment: wouldn't it be a hoot if the posted code actually compiled.  At a minimum it is missing the #include statements for the needed header files.  and `call()` is a non void function but has no `return value;` statement.   Suggest compiling with all warnings enabled, then fix those warnings.

Comment: when calling the function: `scanf()`, always check the returned value (not the parameter value)  to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: When coding, use meaningful names.  this applies to both function names and variable names.  In general, function names should include some action verb and variable names should include a hint of the contents of the variable and/or its' usage.

Comment: What happens when the first call to scanf() returns a value greater than 10?   The code contains some 'magic' numbers.  'magic' numbers make the code difficult to understand, a major headache to debug and/or maintain.  Suggest using #define or an enum for each 'magic' number to give it a meaningful name then using that meaningful name throughout the code.

Comment: why on earth would you pass such defective code to `codechef`?  best to (at least) fix the compile problems first.

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting SIGSEGV, it means you're trying to access memory in a segment your program does not have access to, or you're trying to access memory your program has access to in an invalid way.

Your first course of action should be to use Valgrind or Dr. Memory, when you have a memory segmentation error like this.

Based on your code, I'd assume you may be having a problem when n > 10 that is causing a buffer overrun in b and x. If you named your parameters to something meaningful, it would be easier for us to solve.